# Callback for "Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I understand that if my app is already running *and* I haven't made any code changes, LogCat displays the following warning:

> ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not
>   started, its current task has been
>   brought to the front

What I don't understand is why no activity lifecycle like onResume() or onRestart() is called.

The app was **not** visible before I tried to re-run it, so why no onResume() or onRestart() callback was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* onResume() is not called? In all of my code I see onResume being called. Perhaps a sample code post showing the contrary.

Comment: According to [this diagram](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/01/android-activity-lifecycle/), an activity cannot possibly be restored into the `Running` state without going through `onResume()`.  This is regardless whether it was in the `Paused` or `Stopped` state. I must have observed things incorrectly and a long time passed since then, so I am accepting your answer unless I can observe otherwise.